# Relation between two variables

Tags: correlation

I have approx 500 variable (each variable containing 80 data points). I need to find how each of the variable is related to other 499 variables - linear, log, exponential and so on. Is there a statistical test which could provide me with this information? I don't want to go through manual process of having trendline and finding the R-squared value.

Help much appreciated :)

Thank you!
Vinay

Answer (score 2):

With 500 variables and all pairwise comparisons, that gives you 124,750 comparisons.  Doing one test on each pair at an alpha of 0.05 would generate over 6,000 false positives (assuming all nulls are true).  If you want to compare between multiple possible relationships that will inflate things even more.  Depending on the variability around the "True" relationship, 80 data points may not be enough to distinguish between the potential relationships (or at least subsets of them).

Also, what are your plans if the "Best" fits are contradictory?  e.g. variables 1 and 2 are linearly related, but 1 is exponential with 3 while 2 is log with 3 (if 1 and 2 are linear then they should have the exact same relationship with 3).  Any automatic method could give results like this even though it would contradict any underlying science.

So basically pulling 124,750 relationships out of a hat (or otherwise generating them randomly) will probably give you as much useful information (with less effort) than any automated method.

If you tell us more about why you think you want all those relationships, and how you plan to use them, basically what is your real and final question, then we may be able to give more useful advice.

Comment: I can increase the datapoints to more than 80. Basically i am trying to find the relationship between sensor data collected at location1...location500 and that's why i have 500 variables. Once i find the relationship, i would like to come up with multiple regression model like  TempAt1 = Log(TempAt2) + 0.4(TempAt3) - Exp(TempAt4). I am considering that i wouldnt have problems if "Best" fits among stations are contradictory. The whole idea would be to reduce the %error of dependent variable to least. Thank you :)

Comment: @VinayKumar, wouldn't it make more sense for all the relationships to be the same? similar?  why would the temperature at one site vary linearly with another site, but exponentially with a 3rd?  Also, the pairwise relationship does not necessarily match the "correct" or "best" relationship in a model with multiple predictors.

Comment: Yes i agree to this. But i thought to learn generic solution (not only temperature) when data is closely related as logarithmic or polynomial scale. Something like what Box-Cox transformation does!!

Comment: Essentially Pearson correlation would give higher value even if the variables are log, squared or squared-root of other variable.